# Is it possible to create OLE DB Provider for a running programma

Tags: c#, oledb, dataprovider, reportbuilder, consumer

At the moment I am researching a way to replace a old Report generator.

Because the company I work for is a Microsoft partner they hope to use the Report Builder 3.0.

The problem is we want it to connect to our own business object and not directly to our database. Due to applied filters, sort, edits, ect.

I thinking it is be possible to write our own OLE DB Adapter so we can connect to our business object with the report builder. I read the "Introduction to OLE DB" on MSDN and there it says

"It is important to distinguish a provider's data source object, which provides data from the data store to a consumer, from the data store itself, which contains the data but interacts with the consumer only through the data source object. For example, a data store might be a comma-separated-value (CSV) text file, an SQL DBMS, or an **in-memory array in an application**."

I take it this means it's possible to connect to a application I just have to figure out how. Can anyone confirm this and possibly supply a sample? (C# preferably but C++ will do aswell)

---

Second Question

The OLE DB exist out of a provider and a consumer. Seeing I want to use the report builder I think that I don't have to write my own consumer seeing report builder creates the connection to the provider. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Do you mean write a OLE DB provider to access a database via a Business Objects universe?

Comment: Did you find this old codeproject sample: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1730/Creating-an-OLE-DB-Data-Provider